# Simulation measured voltage not matching calculations

Tags: simulation, voltage-divider, ohms-law

Ok, so I have the following circuit:
[image]

[click here for simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.200277308269968%2050%205%2043%0Aw%20112%20144%20176%20144%200%0Ar%20176%20144%20240%20144%200%201000%0Aw%20240%20144%20288%20144%200%0Aw%20288%20144%20288%2096%200%0Ar%20288%2096%20368%2096%200%201200%0Ar%20288%20144%20368%20144%200%204700%0Aw%20368%2096%20368%20144%200%0Aw%20368%20144%20432%20144%200%0Aw%20432%20144%20432%20240%200%0Aw%20112%20144%20112%20240%200%0Av%20320%20240%20240%20240%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20112%20240%20240%20240%200%0Aw%20320%20240%20432%20240%200%0Aw%20288%2096%20288%2032%200%0Aw%20368%2096%20368%2032%200%0Ap%20288%2032%20368%2032%200%0Ao%2015%2064%200%20550%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0A)

The source voltage is 5V.

The voltage measured between A and B is 2.44V, which differs from what I get by calculating that same voltage - 2.55. Here is how I am calculating it.

R1=1000

R2=1/(1/1.2*1000+1/4.7*1000) //adding voltages of parallel resistors using the 1/Rt = 1/R1+1/R2 formula

Rtotal=R1+R2

Vab=R1/Rtotal*5V

Vab=2.55 //calculated result using MS Mathematics because I am a lazy piece of shit

As you can see there is a difference of 0.11V. Is that normal or is there another reason as to why it happens? Am I doing something wrong? Is the simulator bugged, maybe?

UPDATE: Here is how I get the exact same value using excel:
[image]

Gonna pick up a pen and paper and see what I get myself.

Comment: my calcs are 2.44367V  what exactly did you do

Comment: @JonRB, see updated question

Comment: What did you get for R2?  I get 955.96 Ohms, resulting in 2.4437 volts.  You should show your intermediate results to aid in troubleshhoting.

Comment: @PeterBennett, I just updated the question with more details :)

Comment: The formula in line 10 is wrong.  It formula should be =(B7/B8) * B9. Line 8 is the result of B1+B7, not B1 + B6 as the table shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake during the calculation of the voltage divider, you need (R2/Rtotal)*5V instead of (R1/Rtotal)*5V, since the Vab is across R2 (Rparallel).

[image]

Comment: I see. Can you please explain why it needs to be like that? I have trouble wrapping my head around it. It just doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: In a voltage divider, the voltage divides across the resistors in proportion to their resistances.  To make the situation easier to visualize, lets replace your parallel resistors with a 2K resistor.  Then the total resistance is 3K.  The voltage across the 1K resistor will be 1/3 of the supply voltage, and across the 2K resistor we will have 2/3 of the supply voltage.